# Dependency Management .Net: Classes or Assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, software-design

If I want my Business domain objects to not depend on the database, should my domain classes be in a separate assembly?

Consider the following:

**Core.dll** - Contains business objects, very limited references

**Application.dll**  - Contains repositories saving business objects to the database. This assembly references SQLClient.dll and other external libraries

**Web.dll** - The web application. Needs a reference to both Core.dll and Application.dll

The limitation of this, is that I can not make good use of access modifiers. There are some methods / data I'd like for the repository classes to have access to but not the classes in Web.DLL.

I have two ways of looking at the problem.

1. Its okay for Core.dll to be merged with Application.dll, as long as the business logic classes to not Import unnecessary libraries (Like SqlClient). Repositories and Domain classes should be in the same assembly because they frequently change together.
2. It's better for Core.dll and Application.dll to be separate, because you can reference Core.DLL without needing references to other libraries (Like  SQLClient). You could share namespaces or use InternalsVisibleTo to create the layer between business objects and Data Access

Which has the community found to be the better practice?

Comment: Why not have a reference to core from application?

Comment: @TonyMathew: I think he's referring to that in his second approach.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your thoughts, I'd definitely go ahead with your second approach, keeping Core, Application and Web separately. As each has its own distinctive components and functionality.